# Calculating Date columns of MysQl in VB.Net?

Tags: mysql, vb.net-2010

I'm using VB.Net 2010 and MySQL.
I have two tables in MySQL database 'CAR' and 'CAR_RENT'.

From the VB.Net I want to do the following calculations:

1. I want to calculate the total_fee Column in CAR_RENT. Which can be multiplying the rental_fee column from 'CAR' table with the date difference of Issue_date and return_date from 'CAR_RENT' table.
2. I want to calculate the penalty_fee column of 'CAR_RENT' table by finding the exceeded date from the return_date. That should be rental_fee*number_of_exceeded_date for specified client.
3. That should be automatically calculated when the program is run.

I know that the code I tried is completely not formal way so no need to post it here. Please I need your help??

```
 TABLE:CAR     
+-----------+----------+---------------+--------+----------------+
| Car_id    | Plate_no | Model         | color  | Rental_fee_day |
| 100       | 25534    | Tesla Model S | Black  | $3500          |
| 101       | 25535    | Audi A6       | Black  | $2100          |
| 103       | 35625    | BMW 3 Series  | silver | $2000          |
+-----------+----------+---------------+--------+----------------+


TABLE:CAR_RENT 
+-----------+--------+------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+
| Client_id | Car_id | Issue_date | Return_date | Total_fee | Penalty_fee |
+-----------+--------+------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+
|         1 |    103 | 2014-02-01 | 2014-02-10  |           |             |
|         1 |    100 | 2014-02-01 | 2014-02-15  |           |             |
|         3 |    101 | 2014-02-18 | 2014-02-30  |           |             |
+-----------+--------+------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

you should check [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff) this is the DateDiff function for mysql.

you can use this and a join to get the info you need....